# How do I set a blank password for the root user in slitaz

Tags: linux, authentication, user-accounts, passwd

I am running slitaz distro, and would like to completely remove the root password. I have tried giving a blank password to the `passwd` command, however that did not seem to do the trick. It gave me an error password was too short, ans it still asked me for a password when I ssh-ed in. The password was just hiting the "Enter" key.

**UPDATE:**
Perhaps it has to do with the fact that slitaz uses dropbear for ssh? Because even with a blank password for root in `/etc/shadow`, it still prompts for a password.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7283/how-can-i-make-a-user-able-to-log-in-with-ssh-keys-but-not-with-a-password

Comment: What you're trying to do is "set a blank password", not "remove the root password".

Removing the root password implies that it has no password, rather than having a blank one.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

● **Do you really want to allow logins without a password?** If so, try `passwd -d root` (see warnings below)

● Do you really want to have an empty password? `echo root: | chpasswd` or, if that is rejected, `echo "root:$(mkpasswd -s </dev/null)" | chpasswd -e` (see warnings below)

● For those coming here in search of a way to **block password login for root**, you have options:

1. `passwd -l root` disables (locks), `passwd -u root` re-enables (unlocks) the root password.
2. sshd option `PasswordAuthentication no` disables password authentification for all users (via ssh)
3. sshd option `PermitRootLogin no` disables root login (via ssh)
4. sshd option `PermitRootLogin prohibit-password` disables root login with password (via ssh)

Notes and warnings:

- ⚠️ Make sure you have a way to log in even if you accidentally lock your password. For example, a second user with full sudo access. (If you try to configure no / an insecure password, your system might actually lock you out.)
- `passwd -d root` can allow for root login without password!
- ⚠️ this is a terrible idea on systems connected to the internet. **Don't do it except in an isolated host or network.** An empty password is arguably worse.
- that's why your system setup might still disallow logins without password (or with empty password) if you remove the password (or set it to the empty string). Especially via SSH.
- SSH with public keys, and something `ssh-agent` is the way to go if you want the convenience of not repeatedly entering your password
- SSH with public keys, and an unencrypted private key is the way to go if you want to run commands from remote scripts. There is a  `PermitRootLogin forced-commands-only` sshd option; when set  the remote script can only trigger specific commands that you need to configure on the server.

Usually, passwords are usually saved in salted&hashed form in `/etc/shadow`. For more information, read the manpage with `man shadow 5`.
Authentication can be blocked in the configuration of the SSH server (see `man sshd_config`) or in the OS's authentification system (see "PAM" - Linux Pluggable Authentication Modules).

Comment: I can't resist the urge to add that having a passwordless root login is in most (all?) cases a bad idea.

Comment: Nope that did not work on my system. This is what I turned up as well from Google.

However it still asks for a password

Comment: Does `passwd -d root` give any error? What's in your `/etc/shadow`?

Comment: no errors. It does what it is supposed to, the /etc/shadow is correct  
  
`root::13525:0:99999:7:::`

Comment: Then you may have an issue with your SSH config: See the [sshd_config(5) manpage](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sshd_config+5), esp. `PermitEmptyPasswords`, `PermitRootLogin`.

Comment: Would this work if you have an shadow file in both /dev/sda3 and /dev/sdb3?

Comment: More likely, rather than having the password for root simply be blank, you'd like to lock the password so that it won't match any input.
`passwd --lock root` or `passwd -l root`

Comment: What @JeremyFelix said is precisely what I needed; that should have been the answer!

Comment: @InternetSeriousBusiness You seem to forget to mention *why* is empty root password a problem. Some time ago I realized that you can `su` from ordinary user account without a password which is a privilege escalation that turns an application exploit into a system exploit.

Comment: I misunderstood this question and answer, and ran this on a public server. I thought it was removing the *option* of a password, as in "removing the ability to login via password". Luckily I had nothing on the server!

Comment: Doesn't empty password allow anyone to login without a password or key? I recall using a boot CD to rescue a system I forgot the password to. I was able to temporarily login from the console by entering nothing as the password.